# Cannot install Flask with pip on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, flask, raspberry-pi, pip

I am trying to install Flask on my Raspberry Pi, but it seems that this is not possible anymore with the command: `sudo pip install flask` . I always return this message:

```
Downloading/unpacking flask
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 194, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_page
    session=self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 694, in get_page
    req, link, "connection error: %s" % exc, url,
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Error)

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Does anybody have an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: coud you post the corresponding content of `/root/.pip/pip.log`?

Comment: The log file shows the same error message again, except one line: Between line one and two comes this entry: Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51154/broken-python-pip-install-what-is-the-correct-way-to-fix).
In short, the fix is to set date correctly, eg:

`sudo date +%Y%m%d -s "20180920"`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, this works for me - you have helped me a lot!!